# erase last element of a vector by reference

Tags: pass-by-reference, rcpp

I would link to shrink a `vector`, which is passed by reference.
To do so, I use `erase` on the last element(s):

```
require(Rcpp)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
cppFunction("void f(IntegerVector &x){                                                                                                                                                                             
    x[1] = 3;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
cppFunction("void g(IntegerVector &x){                                                                                                                                                                             
    x.erase(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
a <- c(1L, 2L)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
a                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
f(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
a                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
g(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
a
```

Output is:

```
[1] 1 2                                                                                                                                                                          
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 3
```

Function `f` shows that I can make it to pass by reference.
However, for some reason I cannot remove the last element with function `g`.
(I can check that the size of the vector does decrease in C++.)

So either:

- It is currently not possible with Rcpp (for good reasons, I am sure, such as memory reallocation).
- I do it wrong.

So is it possible to remove the last element(s) of a vector in C++, and get it back in R?

**EDIT**:
I want to pass by reference because I use large data sets (here, a `tibble` with hundreds of millions of rows).
Copying is non-optimal here.

Comment: First options is correct. Rcpp vectors are thin wrappers around R objects. And R objects cannot be resized in place. They are reallocated when resized. To get it back you must reallocate `a <- g(a)` with `IntegerVector g(IntegerVector x)`

Comment: @JRR: I see.  So it is impossible to "resize-by-reference".  Could I accept this as answer... if you want to copy your comment to the answers?  (Note that I edited the question so that I explained why I wanted to pass by reference.)

Comment: You are also missing long and extended discussion as to why 'by reference' doesn't just work.  See for example answer 5.1 in the [Rcpp FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) which is closely related.  The objects you pass are _always_ the `SEXP` objects which are pointers internally to the memory.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Most informative!  Still, I use the `&` as syntactic sugar, because it is closer to what I expect, coming from the C++ community.

Comment: I know. I do too at times. White lies...

Comment: And I guess we are then making _reference_ copies to the (small, anyway) `SEXP` object which is fine.  But you need to keep an in mind, and maybe document for users of your code that removing the `&` does _not_ magically give you constness, nor does adding `const`.  We could possibly add that with a fair amount of extra work; nobody has volunteered yet...